# What kind of programming language or software can simulate the user interaction with browser?

Tags: browser, webrat

Hi I am looking for some kind of software(web rat)/some type of programming lanuages can simulate the user interaction with browser. Like the capybara for the cucumber test in rails.

The situation is I want that (software/script languages) to open the browser and login to the forum and click on some link every day.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Selenium at seleniumhq.org.